# save multiple rows into database from dynamic input fields using laravel/JQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

I'm trying to insert data into database from dynamic input fields, that is each additional input field should be inserted into database in a row with a primary key.

So I'm using the following view and script which adds dynamically input fields.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("body").on("click", ".add_new_frm_field_btn", function() {
    var random = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000); //generate random values..
    var index = $(".form_field_outer").find(".form_field_outer_row").length + 1;
    //added data-index and outer..class
    $(".form_field_outer").append(`<div class="col-12 outer" data-index="${index}_${random}"><div class="card-body form_field_outer_row"> <div class="form-row"><div class="form-group col-md-4"> <label for="inputState">Casting</label><select id="id_casting" class="form-control" name="rows[${index}][id_casting]">
    <option selected>Choose...</option><option data-id="{{$casting->id_casting}}" value="{{$casting->id_casting}}">{{$casting->nom.' '.$casting->prenom}}</option> </select></div><div class="form-group col-md-4"><label for="inputState">Type de contrat</label><select id="id_modele_contrat" class="form-control" name="rows[${index}][id_modele_contrat]"> <option selected>Choose...</option><option>...</option> </select></div><div class="card-body "><button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-warning mb-1 remove_node_btn_frm_field">Delete</button></div>
    </div></div></div> `);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="col-12">
  <div class="card mb-4 form_field_outer">
    <!--added outer and data-index-->
    <div class="card-body form_field_outer_row outer" data-index="0">
      <form>
        <div class="form-row">
          <div class="form-group col-md-4">
            <label for="inputState">Casting</label>
            <select id="id_casting" class="form-control" name="rows[0][id_casting]">
              <option selected>Choose...</option>
              <option data-id="{{$casting->id_casting}}" value="{{$casting->id_casting}}">{{$casting->nom.' '.$casting->prenom}}</option>
            </select>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group col-md-4">
            <label for="inputState">Type de contrat</label>
            <select id="id_modele_contrat" class="form-control" name="rows[0][id_modele_contrat]">
              <option selected>Choose...</option>
              <option>...</option>
            </select>
          </div>
          <div class="card-body ">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-warning mb-1 remove_node_btn_frm_field">Delete</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-warning mb-1 add_new_frm_field_btn">Add</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>

  </div>


</div>
<div>
```

And the following Controller :

```
 data = $request->input('rows');
    foreach($data[0] as $key => $value) {

                  Projet_Casting::create([
                     'id_projet' =>  1,
                     'id_casting' => $value,
                     'id_contrat'  => 1,
]);
    }
```

When I add for example 4 input fields it inserts into database only the two first additional input fields and not the 4 additional input fields.

When I did :

```
 dd($data[0]);
```

I get :

```
array:2 [
  "id_casting" => "20"
  "id_modele_contrat" => "1"
]
```

is there something wrong with my Html and jQuery code or in my controller ?

Please help

**Update**

Model :

```
class Projet_Casting extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = ["id_projet_casting", "id_projet","id_casting","id_contrat",
       "actif"
    ];
 
  protected $guarded = [];
 protected $primaryKey = 'id_projet_casting';

 protected $table = 'projets_castings';


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing loop

```
if(isset($data)&&count($data)){
    foreach($data as $key => $value) {
        
      Projet_Casting::create([
           'id_projet' =>  1,
            'id_casting' => $value['id_casting'],
             'id_contrat'  => $value['id_modele_contrat'],
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer , but when I did that I get this error : `message: "Array to string conversion"`

Comment: the output of dd($data ); : `array:1 [
  0 => array:2 [
    "id_casting" => "20"
    "id_modele_contrat" => "1"
  ]
]`

Comment: @user14053977 looks good.check ocne where you get error message: "Array to string conversion" line also see model for fillable

Comment: for example I'm adding 3 rows of input fields it should be `array:3 [   0 ` and not  `array:1 [   0 `

Comment: @user14053977 if you are adding dynamic fields then for each row you have to increment rows[1][id_casting] ,rows[2][id_casting] etc

Comment: @user14053977 as larvel part is correct and it should work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234646/discussion-between-john-lobo-and-user14053977).